# Powershell: Extract data between 2 strings, in the newest file in directory

Tags: string, powershell, logging, output

My powershell script is supposed to do the following:

- Read the data from the newest log file in the directory
- Output only the relevant data in an output file on my desktop.

At the moment, i get the entire line everytime the word "lobbyid" appears in the document.

My code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  "C:\Program Files\Example\logs" |Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-String –Pattern "lobbyid"| Select Filename,Line | Format-Table -wrap | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\output.txt -append'
```

On a log file containing

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
{"seqid":5,"lobbyid":"9A74E75D-2BCB-4750-BF3A-87BB4992DC2D","mm":{"status":7}
{"seqid":12,"lobbyid":"CFDAAA9C-F973-40CF-A477-143A5810061D","mm":{"status":10}
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

I get

```
{"seqid":5,"lobbyid":"9A74E75D-2BCB-4750-BF3A-87BB4992DC2D","mm":{"status":7}
{"seqid":12,"lobbyid":"CFDAAA9C-F973-40CF-A477-143A5810061D","mm":{"status":10}
```

But I would like the output

```
    Line 1: 9A74E75D-2BCB-4750-BF3A-87BB4992DC2D
    Line 2: CFDAAA9C-F973-40CF-A477-143A5810061D
```

Or something similar. I tried replacing **"lobbyid"** with **'lobbyid(.*?)mm'**
But that gave the same output.

Comment: If you want the line number, you can't use the pipeline that searches through the contents to find the matches.  You have to loop through each line of the file to get the relevant line number.  If all you want are those GUIDs (without the line number), there is a simple modification to your existing code which would make that happen.

Comment: The line number isn't important, so if you could elaborate on that simple modification, that would be enormously helpful

Comment: @thepip3r, `Select-String` uses "line numbers" even with pipeline input to reflect the `1`-based input-object index; try `'foo' | Select-String 'o' | select LineNumber, Line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (which doesn't include a line number, which, as you've stated in a follow-up comment, isn't important; also, the `Out-File` call is omitted for brevity):

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\Example\logs' |
  Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1 | 
      Select-String –Pattern '"lobbyid":"([^"]+)' |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```